# creating php database and displaying its contents

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

```
<?php
```

Used to display errors

```
  ini_set("display_errors",1);
```

error_reporting(E_ALL);

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "1702520";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";
```

I'm new to php and I'm not sure if the code bellow is necessary as i have been trying to make this page using basic online tutorials

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error)
 {  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);}
```

I'm trying to create a database that contains a name, an image, description and a ID

```
 // Create database
 $sql = "CREATE DATABASE myDB";
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
```

echo "Database created successfully";
     } else { echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error; }

Creating the database table

```
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE Data(
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  hname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  himage VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
  hdesc VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
   )";
```

Inserting data into the database (sorry I'm new to php so if there is a more efficient way to insert data into a database i would be happy to know about it)

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO Data (id, hname,himage,hdesc)
 VALUES (1,name1,image address,desc1)"

$sql = "INSERT INTO Data (id, hname,himage,hdesc)
VALUES (2,name2,image address,desc2)"

$sql = "INSERT INTO Data (id, hname,himage ,hdesc)
VALUES (3,name3,image address, desc3)"
```

checks if table was created properly

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
{ echo "Table Data created successfully"; } else {  echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;  }
```

gets the data from the database

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Data ");
 $conn->close();



?>
```

trying to display all the data in the database

```
<html>

 <table border="2" style= "background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>image</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
      while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
        echo
        "<tr>
          <td>{$row\['id'\]}</td>
          <td>{$row\['hname'\]}</td>
          <td>{$row\['himage'\]}</td>
          <td>{$row\['hdesc'\]}</td> 
        </tr>\n";
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
 <?php mysql_close($connector); ?>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: You created connection using `mysqli` and later you are trying to show data using `mysql` way. Don't mess up with `mysql` and `mysqli`, instead I suggest use the later. See how you can select data from database and show on your html table https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Answer (score 1):

**Your Question is Unclear, but I think mean the Data are not displayed from the DataBase?**

*use foreach $row. and you didnt echo the output. I have re written the Database output code Please Replace this with your Old Code.*

```
<?php
      while( $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
        foreach ($row1 as $row){
?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php $row['id'] ?></td>
          <td><?php $row['hname'] ?></td>
          <td><?php $row['himage'] ?></td>
          <td><?php $row['hdesc'] ?></td> 
        </tr>
<?php
        }
      }
?>
```

Comment: This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.

Comment: He didn't mentioned the PHP Version and I have correct the mysql to mysqli Thanks for informing.

Comment: glad you understood and change your code. +1 vote for that.:)

Comment: Thank you @BeingSunny ;) 

Comment: @mmmmmkeyisstuckmmmmmmmmmm So have you got the output? then vote me up :)